# AudioKit requesting access to microphone

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I just updated AudioKit and XCode to the latest versions. Now when I run my app A popup comes up requesting access to the microphone. I am not using the microphone in any of my AudioKit code. As far as I remember the previous version never requested microphone access. Was there a change from previous versions I need to be aware of?

Comment: This is common when using a simulator even when you're not recording.  Its default behavior now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Alex Bailey said, when using a simulator it defaults to asking for a microphone access, even though your app doesn't require that feature. If your build and run your app on a device you shouldn't see the request access for microphone.